# nchar(1) column at MS SQL Server case-insensitive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case-insensitive

I run this code on MS SQL Server:

```
select  * 
from    information_schema.columns 
where   table_name = 'prod__lookup_api'

select  *
from    prod__lookup_api    as a
where   a.code = 'c'    AND
        a.code = 'C'
```

and I get [these](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dgIaqNJ0WsBUqDunUXh04yWAXL2HQvwq/view?usp=sharing) results.

Comment: [Collation and Unicode support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15): "Collations in SQL Server provide sorting rules, case, and accent sensitivity properties for your data"

Comment: Please don't post results on an external site. Questions should be self-contained. There are [sites](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) that will allow you to quickly turn SQL results into something presentable.

Answer (score 0):

ok: CI collation: Greek_CI_AS.